# Uploaded a package to PPA but it's not showing and no email from Launchpad

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I uploaded a package to my PPA over three hours ago, with no response from Launchpad.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have had upload emails take over five hours before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Dobey in #launchpad](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/09/05/%23launchpad.html#t14:42), if you do not get a response via e-mail, the package doesn't show up in your PPA, and everything looks to be okay; then it's likely the GPG key you signed the package with isn't in Launchpad. Add you GPG key to Launchpad and re-upload the package.

If you get the message that the package is already uploaded, delete the `*source.ppa.upload` file, or add the `-f` flag to `dput`.

Comment: Would be great if this was more proeminent in the docs... But you made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that that the version is greater than all previous versions of the same package. See [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) reference for information on how versions are ordered.

If this is the problem you should get a message when you try to upload, but won't get any e-mail or other result.