# Uploaded package not showing in my Launchpad PPA

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad, debuild, dput

I created a package for Launchpad PPA and want to upload it to Launchpad. I've used `dput` command and this is what I get:

```
tomica@home:~/Desktop$ dput ppa:{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
Uploading packagename using ftp to ppa (host: ppa.launchpad.net; directory: ~{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa)
running supported-distribution: check whether the target distribution is currently supported (using distro-info)
{'allowed': ['release'], 'known': ['release', 'proposed', 'updates', 'backports', 'security']}
running required-fields: check whether a field is present and non-empty in the changes file
running checksum: verify checksums before uploading
running suite-mismatch: check the target distribution for common errors
running check-debs: makes sure the upload contains a binary package
running gpg: check GnuPG signatures before the upload
Uploading packagename_0.0.1.dsc
Uploading packagename_0.0.1.tar.gz
Uploading packagename_0.0.1_source.buildinfo
Uploading packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
tomica@home:~/Desktop$
```

I would think that this means my upload was successful. However, [when I visit my PPA, it's empty](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomicakorac/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). Why is that?

If I try to upload my package again, this is what I get:

```
tomica@home:~/Desktop$ dput ppa:{MY_LAUNCHPAD}/ppa packagename_0.0.1_source.changes
Package packagename was already uploaded to ppa
If you want to upload nonetheless, use --force or remove packagename_0.0.1_source.ppa.upload
tomica@home:~/Desktop$
```

This means that my package should be visible and accessible, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you given launchpad time to build the package (it's not super quick; email is often the clue that it failed/built..)

Comment: Since it says `running supported-distribution: check whether the target distribution is currently supported (using distro-info)`, does the latest entry in the changelog have an ubuntu release name, e.g. `focal`,`groovy` or `bionic`?

Comment: @guiverc it's been 2 hours. Also, shouldn't my package also be visible in the builders' list? I can't find it here: https://launchpad.net/builders

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it does, it's set to `groovy`.

Comment: May be related https://askubuntu.com/a/184392/124466 . Also, https://askubuntu.com/a/443136/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no, I did not receive any email. From Launchpad's help, this might mean that my <source.changes> file was not signed, or that my signature isn't published, but both of these are incorrect: my source.changes is signed with a signature that exists in my Launchpad PPA.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I found those, unfortunately none of them helped.

Comment: You can ask a question in Launchpad as well https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, here's the explanation:

1. The package was getting rejected because Launchpad builder could not parse non-latin name in 'Maintainer' field in `debian/control` file. This is considered a bug and was reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1910403
2. Because of the same bug, notification emails were not getting sent, and so I could not know what the reason was.

To clarify this, I was assisted by good people at https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/694768. @ArchismanPanigrahi many thanks for suggesting to ask there.